# how to make model,viewmodel from the url

Tags: ios

how to make model,viewModel and DataSourceModel for this type of api.

```
{"data":[{"id":45,"question":"Were the answers that staff provided to your questions presented in a way that you could understand?","options":["Yes, always","Yes, sometimes","No""Other"]}]}
```

this is my api.

According to my design i am using tableview section So in the header the questions will display and in the tableviewcell the list of options will display.

output as :-

```
Were the answers that staff provided to your questions presented in a way that you could understand?

Yes, always
Yes, sometimes
No
Other
```

this way i need to display.

My code is as below:-

model:-

```
classQuestionListModel: NSObject {
    var home:[OPTIONS] = []


    var id:String?
    var question:String?
    var options:[String]?
    var v:String?
    init?(dictionary :JSONDictionary) {

        guard
            let question = dictionary["question"] as? String,
            let id = dictionary["id"] as? String


            else {
                return

        }

        if let options = dictionary["options"] as? [String]{
            print(options)


        }


        self.question = question
        self.id = id
         }

}
```

viewmodel:-

```
 func numberOfSections(tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
        print((datasourceModel.dataListArray?.count)!)
        return (datasourceModel.dataListArray?.count)!
    }

    func titleForHeaderInSection(atsection section: Int) -> QuestionListModel {
        return datasourceModel.dataListArray![section]
    }


   func numberOfRowsInSection(section:Int) -> Int {
        print(self.tableArray[section].count)
            return self.tableArray[section].count
  }


  func datafordisplay(atindex indexPath: IndexPath) -> OPTIONS{

       // print(datasourceModel.dataListArray![indexPath.section].options)

     return datasourceModel.dataListArray![indexPath.row]

   // return  values

 }
```

in viewcontroller:-

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return reviewViewModel.numberOfSections(tableView: tableView)
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {



        let identifier = "HeaderCell"

        var headercell: questionheader! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? questionheader

        if headercell == nil {
            tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "questionheader", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
            headercell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? questionheader
        }

        headercell.setReviewData(reviews:reviewViewModel.titleForHeaderInSection(atsection:section))

     headercell.setReviewData(reviews:reviewViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: section))

        return headercell
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

        return 63

    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return reviewViewModel.numberOfRowsInSection(section: section)
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let identifier = "Cell"
        var cell: QuestionListCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? QuestionListCell

        if cell == nil {
            tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "QuestionListCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? QuestionListCell
        }
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear


      cell.question.text = reviewViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath)


        print(reviewViewModel.tableArray)

        return cell
         }
```

in questionlistcell:-

```
class 
QuestionListCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imagebutton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var options: UILabel!
      var i = 0
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code




    }

    func setReviewData(reviews:QuestionListModel)

    {

        print(reviews.options)




     self.question.text = reviews.v






    }


    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

Comment: how to solve it?

Comment: what's the problem you are facing?

Comment: i need to create the method for datafordisplay in tableview at viewmodel and  it should call in the cell for rowindex .

Comment: @LalKrishna how to solve the problem

Comment: You already did that- `cell.question.text = reviewViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath)` . I'm confused,

Comment: here showing the error in reviewViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath).I think some changes needed to do.Or if u confused still....My question is according to my api as i uploaded the data how to display the data in mvvm method.

Comment: What's the return type of `datafordisplay:`

Comment: i have given as:------- func datafordisplay(atindex indexPath: IndexPath) -> QuestionListModel {
         
    
     return self.tableArray[indexPath.section]
   
 }

  this in viewmodel and in viewcontroller as:---------------- in cellforrow at indexpath as     cell.setReviewData(reviews: reviewViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))   in question list cell as:----------- func setReviewData(reviews:NH_QuestionListModel)
        
    {     self.question.text = reviews.v
        }   here how to solve it

Comment: So the error is clear. `cell.question.text` is expecting a string, & you passed `QuestionListModel`. It should be `cell.question.text = reviewViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath).question`

Answer (score 0):

`cell.question.text` is expecting a string, & you passed `QuestionListModel`. 
It should be

```
if let question = reviewViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath).question {
    cell.question.text = question
}
```

Comment: what should give in datadordisplay function in viewmodel?

Comment: func datafordisplay(atindex indexPath: IndexPath) -> NH_QuestionListModel {
         
    
     return self.tableArray[indexPath.section]
   
 }  according to this code showing an error as :-cannot convert return expression of type[String] to return type model